# R giving back error: subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, plot, statistics, mse

I have been working my way through R ISLR College dataset and I'm wanting to perform the best subset selection on the training set, and plot the training set MSE associated with the best model of each size.

```
library(ISLR)
library(leaps)
data(College)
head(College)

#splitting the data into 70/30
subset<- sample(nrow(college)*0.7)
collegetrain<- college[subset,]
collegetest<-college[-subset,]
```

This is my code:

```
regfit.full <- regsubsets(apps ~ ., data = college.train, nvmax = 20)
train.mat <- model.matrix(apps ~ ., data = college.train, nvmax = 20)
val.errors <- rep(NA, 20)
for (i in 1:20) {
coefi <- coef(regfit.full, id = i)
pred <- train.mat[, names(coefi)] %*% coefi
val.errors[i] <- mean((pred - college.train$y)^2)
}
plot(val.errors, xlab = "Number of predictors", ylab = "Training MSE", pch = 19, type = "b")
```

The dataset is structured like this:
777 observations with **543 in the training set and 234 in the test set**.
There are 18 variables with 17 of them being numeric and 1 being a factor of yes and no *(this doesn't need to be changed).*

The **error message** i get when i run my code is:
**Error in s$which [id, , drop=FALSE]: subscript out of bounds**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
regfit.full <- regsubsets(Apps ~ ., data = collegetrain, nvmax = 20)
train.mat <- model.matrix(Apps ~ ., data = collegetrain, nvmax = 20)

val.errors <- rep(NA, 20)
for (i in 1:17) {
  coefi <- coef(regfit.full, id = i)
  pred <- train.mat[, names(coefi)] %*% coefi
  val.errors[i] <- mean((pred - collegetrain$Apps)^2)
}

plot(val.errors, xlab = "Number of predictors", ylab = "Training MSE", 
     pch = 19, type = "b")
```